# How do you find voltage across a capacitor in a circuit with two voltage sources?

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor

[image]
My textbook shows the circuit below and says that before the switch is opened, the voltage across the capacitor is 2V. Why does the 8V voltage source not have an effect on the capacitor's voltage?

Comment: If the capacitor is directly connected to a 2V ideal voltage source, what else could define the voltage?

Comment: Does the 8V source not have any effect on it?

Comment: @YSKIM, the 8 V source an 10 kohm resistor determine how much current the 2 V source must sink in order to hold its output (and the capacitor) voltage at 2 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideal voltage source tries to keep a constant potential difference across its terminals. Voltage of the capacitor would be 2V at t=0 if you assume that the switch has been closed for a long time (from t = - ∞). Initial voltage of the capacitor would be \$V_c(0_-) = V_c(0_+) = 2V \$. With that you can calculate voltage of the capacitor at t using this equation. The effect of 8V source begins when the switch is open.

$$ V_c(t) = V_c(∞) + (V_c(0_+) -V_c(∞))e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} $$.

\$t=0_-\$ means the event the switch is closed whereas \$t =0_+\$ means the event when switch is open. At t=∞, the voltage of the capacitor would be 8V. Usually in about five time constants, the voltage of capacitor is nearly 8V. In practical measurements, a switch is closed for a long time means a few seconds as even a second is a eternity in DC circuits.